# CakePHP: Define an image URL into a Variable

Tags: php, cakephp, variables, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to define a variable for an Image URL which is something like this:

`http://MyWebSite.com/app/webroot/upload/foods/2/beef_wellington_thumb.jpg`

The number 2 digit in the link is an $id and also represents the folder number. The image file name is originally `beef_wellington.jpg`. But I have to display it using an additional underscore:`_thumb` for each image file name due to an upload component (plugin) I'm using in Cake. So how should I go about in defining a variable for that: e.g.

`$itemImageurl = "/app/webroot/upload/foods/".$id./$item['Food']['image'];`

What about the `_thumb` ? could we place it somewhere in the line of code above?

> UPDATE:

Assuming I have changed the upload plugin so I can also add my original image file name in my folder as this:

`http://MyWebSite.com/app/webroot/upload/foods/2/beef_wellington.jpg`

without needing `_thumb`

How to write the correct variable, I'm not sure about this:

`$itemImageurl = "/app/webroot/upload/foods/".$id./$item['Food']['image'];`

Comment: If you're trying to access this file (/app/webroot/upload/foods/$id/$item['Food']['image']) via the URI, it will be http://example.com/upload/foods/etc).  app/webroot are only for accessing via filesystem.  I also recommend you use cake's built-in constants (rather than app/webroot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about finding the last dot in $item['Food]['image] and replace it with "_thumb."?

e.g. (not tested):

```
$newName = basename("/app/webroot/upload/foods/".$id./$item['Food']['image'],".jpg");
$newName = newName."_thumb.jpg";
```

does it work?